# Using Git to push RStudio Project code to TFS

Tags: git, tfs, rstudio, rstudio-server

I use TFS as a repository for SourceCode, and am trying to set up the workflow from RStudio to push code updates into TFS. I have Git installed on my RStudio server and can commit changes locally. 
Is it possible to use Shell commands in RStudio to upload code to my TFS repository? (I have tried various commands like "git remote add origin" but have not gotten anything to work.)

Comment: What commands are you calling and what is the message that you get?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add your TFS repo as a remote and push.